# How to know if Objective C pointer is of `Class` type?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to know if a pointer in my program is pointing to a Class type.

Something like:

```
if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[Class class]]])
```

This an error because `[Class class]` does not exist.

The closet I can come to is this:

```
    NSLog(@"Will run");
    const char *nameOfClass = class_getName(@"DoesNotExist");
    if (nameOfClass == NULL || (strlen(nameOfClass) == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Not a class");
    } else { 
        NSLog(@"String: %s", nameOfClass);
    }
    NSLog(@"Did run");
```

Where an empty `const char *nameOfClass` would tell me that it isn't in fact a `Class` object. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an Obj-C runtime function called [`object_isClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418659-object_isclass?language=objc).

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
if (object_isClass(anObject))
```

Another valid approach would be to use `class_isMetaClass(object_getClass(anObject))`, since the class of a class is a [metaclass](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html).